# Parse query not returning new data on onResume

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing a feature where users can join a room and I'm using Parse to hold the room's data. My problem is that when a new user joins a room and an existing user of that room resumes the room's activity, the existing user doesn't see the new user.

[image: Entry before a user joined]

So here's an entry for my table where a user created a room but no one's joined yet.

Here's my GameOnSession class which is an extension of the ParseObject class.

```
@ParseClassName("GameOnSession")
public class GameOnSession extends ParseObject {
    public JSONArray getParticipants() { return getJSONArray("participants"); }

    public String getNumberOfParticipants() {
        int getParticipantsNumber = getParticipants().length();
        return String.valueOf(getParticipantsNumber);
    }

    public static ParseQuery<GameOnSession> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(GameOnSession.class);
    }
}
```

This is my query that I run to check the number of people in the room.

```
ParseQuery<GameOnSession> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(GameOnSession.class);
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", QueryPreferences.getStoredSessionId(getActivity()));
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<GameOnSession>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<GameOnSession> objects, ParseException e) {
        GameOnSession sess = objects.get(0);
        Log.d("GAMEONSESSION", "Current # " + sess.getNumberOfParticipants());
    }
});
```

So it returns what I expect: 0.

Now when a new user joins the room, the entry looks like this.

[image: Entry after a user joined]

Then I press a button that runs the query above. And it **still** returns 0, when I expect 1.

I'm not sure what's the problem here, did I set up my query wrong?

In short, when User A creates a room, the Parse query returns number of users as 0 which is **expected**. When User B joins User A's room, Parse query **STILL** returns the numbers of users as 0 and **NOT** 1. This is unexpected and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Remember that Parse will retire next year so if you are using parse till next year then your app wont work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the cause of why my application wouldn't correctly query the database. The reason was that I called Parse to "enableLocalDatastore" so whenever I tried a new query, the application would query from the cached result.

So what I did was disable local datastore and everything's working as expected.

Funny thing was, my team and I that's building this application enable local datastore in the beginning of the development cycle (6 months ago) to test a small feature and forgot to disable it. Technical debt is a PITA.

So if your Parse query is not returning what you expect even though the database clearly shows what you've done, check that you haven't enabled your local datastore!